# css breadbrumbs breaking on ipad zoom

Tags: ipad, css, breadcrumbs

Here's hoping someone can help me please.

I am experimenting with some nice breadcrumbs using css, before this I was using some ugly background images which was less than ideal.

I found this page: http://codepen.io/stryju/pen/kHrAE
Which gave me the code to get started with this!

I have since implemented on a test site: http://test.glow-sticks.org/justbread.php

All looks fine on a desktop computer, however when testing on the iPad and zooming in slightly then it starts to go wrong, small (1px) transparent vertical gaps appear between the arrow section and the rectangular section.

I've noticed on the codepen.io site example you cannot zoom in, which in a sense is a fix, but I prefer the idea of letting the viewer being able to zoom in if they choose to.

It's also worth noting that I tend to view my desktop chrome browser at 125% as default to make things a little easier to see and when doing this ctrl + a few times you can see the edges seem to get slightly jagged. Not too fussed about this, but thought it might be related.

Any ideas? TIA

Comment: Pertaining to why it is jagged when you zoom in on a comp, the `before` or `after` triangle is off by 1 pixel.

Comment: As you said before you can remove the zoom, I recommend you do that. If the site is responsive it will look fine on an ipad anyways which will make the zoom effect less useful. You can always add a button to increase the font-size as well if this is needed. (lot of text or like a book app) This is how you would remove zoom > `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;">` and this part of that `user-scalable=0` is what removes the zoom function. A fiddle I made to increase font size > http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/BzUqM/